# NullPointerException on creation of JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I'm making a call to an API using Volley in my app. And the call to convert the String response to a JSONArray fails with a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

I don't understand why there is a NullPointerException. I verified that I'm getting a response from the API so i should not be passing a null string to the JSONArray constructor. This is the code snippet. The exception occurs in the try-catch block.

```
String requestUrl = "https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards?key="+keys.apiKeyTrello+"&token="+savedToken;

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        boardListView.setText("Response is: " + response);
        copyResponse = new String(response);
        Log.d("timer", "reached here");
    }
},
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            copyResponse = new String("[{\"error\":\"error\"}]");
            boardListView.setText("That didn't work!");
    }
});

queue.add(stringRequest);

try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(copyResponse); // NullPointerException here
}
catch (JSONException e){
    //Handle exception
}
```

A sample response from the API is here: http://pastebin.com/Bs2GYPcC

The stacktrace is like so:

```
10-09 19:28:03.856 3535-3535/im.chaitanya.pomodorotimer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 19:28:03.856 3535-3535/im.chaitanya.pomodorotimer E/AndroidRuntime: Process: im.chaitanya.pomodorotimer, PID: 3535
10-09 19:28:03.856 3535-3535/im.chaitanya.pomodorotimer E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{im.chaitanya.pomodorotimer/im.chaitanya.pomodorotimer.ShowBoardList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
10-09 19:28:03.856 3535-3535/im.chaitanya.pomodorotimer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
```

Comment: may be your copyResponse is not initialized it going int to another thread you will get it on response or in error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String request is executed asynchronously, so at the time you call the method inside the try - catch the variable is not yet initialised and it fails with a `NullPointerException`.

I suggest you move the code in the try catch to the `onSuccess()` and the `onErrorResponse` method. This way it will be called after you have received the response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `copyResponse` in the onResponse method, so it is null before onResponse is called (asynchronous call).

If you try to parse your JSONArray in the onResponse method it should work. Something like :

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
    boardListView.setText("Response is: " + response);
    //copyReponse is useless here. You can directly use response
    Log.d("timer", "reached here");
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```